# Failed to install windows 10 from usb drive on HP 255 G6 (Errors: 0601, 03F0)

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, hp-laptop

I have laptop **hp255 g6** (ssd, 16gb ram, amd a6 with radeon r4 graphics) **~4 years**.
I tried to **install windows 10 pro from usb flash drive** but i have one of this:

- endless reboot (appears hp logo and then reboot)
- strange screen like old TVs (photo attached)
- stuck on hp logo

Then I **get ssd** and **insert it in my pc**, and install windows there. Then i **set it back to laptop**, but **same happens**. (On pc windows works well)

Also I tried to do **memory** and **hard drive** tests.
**Result: Passed**.

**System log in bios:** (both multiple times)

- 0601
- 03F0

Also I **tried to install linux** (manjaro, ubuntu) and it **works well**, unlike windows.

*What can cause this?*

[image: pic1]

Comment: At first glance I would say the problem is the GPU, and the reason Linux works, is due to NOT using the display driver (in other words it’s pure luck).  How confident are you the hardware is good?  Have you actually installed the display drivers on Linux and set the resolution to the desired resolution?

Comment: @Ramhound I not sure about hardware, because laptop is a bit old. About drivers: i’ll try to install linux again and test. Also, when it starts there is normal hp logo. Bios is ok too.

Comment: @Ramhound is there any solutions to make laptop work?

Comment: Do you have the equipment required to more than likely resolder a GPU to the board and the soldering skills to remove the current one?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but in this cpu, gpu is integrated. So i think the best way is to change it, but i afraid that it can be embedded in motherboard.

Comment: You are not going to be able to change a mobile processor.  I assume you are not in a situation to take the device to somebody that could diagnose it further?

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, so there is no ways how to run windows?

Comment: I will go back to my first point, I believe this to be a hardware problem, and you are only able to boot into Linux since you are not installing the display drivers. You likely would encounter a kernel error if you did.  The display artifacts in your screenshot indicate your APU is toast.

Comment: @Ramhound okay, i’ll test and write back.

Comment: @Ramhound, I instaled linux mint and run gpu test [heaven](https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven). And I see no artifacts. Result: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/CeVTSHc)

Comment: @Naziks Please check your bios version on your laptop and and then check on the HP support page which is the latest version. Is your Bios Version outdated update your bios and then try the Windows 10 Installation again.

Comment: @Naziks - Sadly your image isn't accessible since you didn't edit your question and use the image upload function.  Can you edit your question to indicate what version of Windows 10 you are attempting to install exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound i’m tring to install Windows 10 Pro 20h2

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy Okay, i’ll try and write back

Comment: @Naziks Any news for us? We would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy Sorry for delay. This is my Bios info: https://i.imgur.com/9sqgXiB.jpg

Comment: @Naziks The bios is out of date. Version F20 is on the device. The current is F53. With version F52, support for Windows 10 version 1909 was added. As already written you should update the BIOS first and then try the installation again.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy How can I update it? I found that i can do this only in windows with app, and with some shortkey after pc starts. How to enter bios update menu and where I can download update for it?

Comment: @Naziks You can find the bios update on the [HP Support Site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers). If you have the possibility, create a USB with a Windows 10 1709 ISO and use it to download the BIOS update and install it. For information to perform the BIOS update, look in the manual on the support website. On this site you can download a Script to create a 1709 ISO under Linux, MacOS and Windows: https://www.uupdump.net/download.php?id=739e1800-9b70-4503-84f0-2b1ba73bfbdc&pack=en-us&edition=core

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy i create USB with bios update, but I cannot install it. I tried some manuals from internet, but no of them works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks **[@Tekkie_Boy](https://superuser.com/users/1108395/tekkie-boy)** and **[@Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)** for your advices!

**My solution:**

1. Download and build old [windows 10 v.1709](https://www.uupdump.net/download.php?id=739e1800-9b70-4503-84f0-2b1ba73bfbdc&pack=en-us&edition=core) (I select v.1709 because this is the latest version which was installed on laptop and works without any troubles).
2. Then use another PC to create **bootable USB drive** using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).
3. Connect USB drive to laptop and install windows.
4. After installation, open [HP Support Site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers) in browser and found my laptop there. In files was attached **BIOS update**, so I download it, install and complete **BIOS update** to latest available.
5. Then I used **my USB drive** and [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to install **windows 10 v.20H2**.
6. After that happens magic and windows was installed ;D

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it has now worked.

Comment: Had the same problem and it also worked for me. The important step is to update BIOS

Comment: I was just about to throw this laptop out the window until I read this. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion this issue was caused by bootloader difference and incompatibility. I will test this solution out. Might even try to install rufus modded win 11 22h2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: works with the latest win 11. Nice.

Answer (score -2):

Download BIOS and Flash him
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjAZ0DTX3aI
WORK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145664)